# Doctrine ODM - like operator syntax

Tags: php, mongodb, sql-like, doctrine-odm

how would i go about simulating the like operator from SQL in doctrine odm?

use case: i want to find a Theme that has somewhere in the field caption string in a variable $search.

How would the query look like?

thanks for all answers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use [MongoRegex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php)

```
$qb->field($field)->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*paliw.*/i'));
```

[source](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/daadb4e3030c196c?pli=1)

But i recomed use separate search engine ([sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/))

Comment: ok, this works. now i want to search the same variable in other field. i tried adding $qb->field('name')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$this->search.'.*/i')); but i get empty results. how to do this?